# Switch playing video to another video on chromecast device

Tags: android, google-chrome, device, chromecast, google-cast

I created a one sample app to validate filters for playing video on Chromecast.

When my device connects to Chromecast, it shows that it is connected and I'm able to play a video on Chromecast device. However, If I want to switch another video, I'm able to switch it and video plyaing also works fine.

But In this case, I want to update the UI,  weather I'm playing a first video or second video? Is there any specific callback to know the mediaplayer status based on user selection on different videos.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of callbacks/listeners that report various changes that happen on the Cast side, such as OnMetadataUpdatedListener or OnStatusUpdatedListener (on Android sender side, similar ones exist on other platforms); I suggest you read our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/sender_apps) and look through our sample or reference [apps](https://github.com/googlecast) and then come back here with issues that you are running into, if any.